# Random BSODs and unexpected behavior (PSU or Motherboard)

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, bsod

I am having random problems with my PC, starting with several random BSODs and a memory dump stating error `SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED`, but I cannot check where the exception occurred since the memory dump has no other valuable information. My specs:

- **MB:** Gigabyte GA-H61M-S1
- **CPU:** I5 2500
- **GPU:** Gefocer 1050 TI
- **RAM:** 2x 4gb Corsair Vengeance
- **PSU:** Seasonic 520w
- **Storage:** SSD (1x), HDD (1x)

I've tried:

- Testing with MemTest and HDD diagnostic tools, receiving no errors
- Removing the SSD and booting only with the HDD, which worked for a couple of days, however upon a reboot, it booted but without video; I changed out the cable from my monitor to the integrated GPU and it worked again, so I removed my GPU, cleaned up, and it worked again
- When I tried to play a game, another freeze occurred, and, after rebooting, I only have 4GB of RAM; I removed both RAM DIMMs, cleaned up, and have 8GB again, but now without the GPU

I suspect the PSU or motherboard is the issue and replaced the PSU with a Corsair CX500 [from another machine] and the PC didn't boot - fans started, but no beeps from the speaker:

- I tried again with the Seasonic, integrated graphics, and a Windows install USB, which worked, connected only the SSD, and upon booting, the SSD is not recognized. I changed the SATA port on my motherboard and the SSD worked.

Besides the PSU and GPU, I don't have any spare hardware to test and am thinking it can only relate to the motherboard. Am I assuming correctly?

Is it more likely to be a motherboard issue or could it be related to something else?

Comment: Have you run the motherboard's built-in hardware diagnostics [extended tests], accessible either from the BIOS/UEFI firmware boot page or from within the BIOS/UEFI firmware settings? When a BSOD occurs, is it listing any other error or file information?

Comment: This is almost certainly a driver error and not a hardware error (could still  be hardware but probably not).  A thread running in the kernel is throwing an exception (gets an error and calls a routine to tell the system that it broke).. there is no code to handle this condition (which is normal in the kernel code).  As @JW0914 points out, we need more information to figure out what actually is breaking.

Comment: @JW0914 I didn't find any diagnostic tool in the BIOS, and have already updated to the latest bios some time ago. And the only information that I have when a BSOB occurs, was the ''SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED'', but just in one BSOD, I got several.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas In the beginning I was suspecting about driver, but when my motherboard was not recognizing some hardware anymore, I became skeptical about it. What kind of new information can I share? 
Could be motherboard battery?

Comment: Suggestion.. use a Linux Live boot disk and see if there are any problems running it? :)  Does Linux crash?  No?  Probably a driver.. Yes?  Probably hardware.

Comment: @Benevides Most motherboards come with built-in hardware diagnostics - you may need to consult the motherboard's user manual on how to boot to it. Have you reviewed [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x7e--system-thread-exception-not-handled)? What Windows version are you running and is the install an upgrade from a previous Windows version _(if so, which one? Non-CPU Win7/8 drivers can cause BSODs in Win10)_? It's most likely 3rd-party driver related, but the BIOS/UEFI hardware diagnostics are vital to rule out hardware components.

Comment: @JW0914 I was sure about driver, but when I got problems before windows initialization, like didn't recognize the GPU, or one memory stick, I started to think that is a hardware problem.  It's a Windows 10 and it's a fresh installed one.
About the BIOS/UEFI hardware diagnostics, I didn't found anything about my motherboard, only for some laptops brand, like DELL, HP, even in the MOBO manuel didn't not have anything.